# Display yAxis label on a diagonal line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I get [example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/xEAxK/) from highcharts :

I'd like to make yAxis label ( 0k,50k..in example) not in vertical line

[image]

but on a diagonal line like this image

[image]

I've been search on highchart's docs but could not found some attribute to do that on yAxis label or maybe I'm wrong ,I've tried some attribute on [highchart's docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels) but still no luck

```
yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0,
    labels: {
      ...
    }
},
```

Please suggest how to do that 
Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate whole graph using `pane.startAngle`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xEAxK/381/

Or wrap method responsible for positioning that points and edit radius to use different than `axis.startAngleRad`: http://jsfiddle.net/xEAxK/385/

Code:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tick.prototype, 'getLabelPosition', function (proceed, x, y, label, horiz, labelOptions, tickmarkOffset, index, step) {
        var rot = this.axis.isXAxis ? this.axis.startAngleRad : -2.5 * Math.PI / 4,
            origRot = this.axis.startAngleRad,
            axis = this.axis,
            optionsY = labelOptions.y,
            ret;

        axis.startAngleRad = rot;

            centerSlot = 20, // 20 degrees to each side at the top and bottom
            align = labelOptions.align,
            angle = ((axis.translate(this.pos) + rot + Math.PI / 2) / Math.PI * 180) % 360;


        if (axis.isRadial) {
            ret = axis.getPosition(this.pos, (axis.center[2] / 2) + H.pick(labelOptions.distance, -25));

            // Automatically rotated
            if (labelOptions.rotation === 'auto') {
                label.attr({
                    rotation: angle
                });

                // Vertically centered
            } else if (optionsY === null) {
                optionsY = axis.chart.renderer.fontMetrics(label.styles.fontSize).b - label.getBBox().height / 2;
            }

            // Automatic alignment
            if (align === null) {
                if (axis.isCircular) {
                    if (this.label.getBBox().width > axis.len * axis.tickInterval / (axis.max - axis.min)) { // #3506
                        centerSlot = 0;
                    }
                    if (angle > centerSlot && angle < 180 - centerSlot) {
                        align = 'left'; // right hemisphere
                    } else if (angle > 180 + centerSlot && angle < 360 - centerSlot) {
                        align = 'right'; // left hemisphere
                    } else {
                        align = 'center'; // top or bottom
                    }
                } else {
                    align = 'center';
                }
                label.attr({
                    align: align
                });
            }

            ret.x += labelOptions.x;
            ret.y += optionsY;

        } else {
            ret = proceed.call(this, x, y, label, horiz, labelOptions, tickmarkOffset, index, step);
        }
        axis.startAngleRad = origRot; 
        return ret;
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

Comment: You make my day Pawel Fus , thank you very much . Now yAxis label at position as I need . Could I keep xAxis label at origin position ?

Comment: Ha! You found a bug in my solution, fixed ;) Try updated answer.